How to fix MPTCP Protocol related errors in Debian12
I am working on a research project and need some help in resolving some errors in MPTCP implementation. I am pasting below the error that I get when I execute a Golang code to initiate communication with a server. I can provide more details required if any expert can help me. Many thanks in advance.
"Error connecting to server via MPTCP (interface 1): dial tcp 192.168.10.5:8080: protocol not available."
Operating System: Debian 12
root@debian:/home/debian# go version
    go version go1.22.4 linux/amd64

I tried different kernel versions.
MPTCP is actually enabled but I can't forward packets using MPTCP.
root@debian:/home/debian# sysctl -a | grep mptcp
    net.ipv4.tcp_available_ulp = mptcp
    net.mptcp.add_addr_timeout = 120
    net.mptcp.allow_join_initial_addr_port = 1
    net.mptcp.checksum_enabled = 0
    net.mptcp.enabled = 1
    net.mptcp.pm_type = 1
    net.mptcp.stale_loss_cnt = 4


Please add more information such as your go code and the commands you executed. Anyway I think go tag is off-topic for this question.
